# Trigger Help - Similar to Roll Up Summary

Tags: apex, trigger

I have several opportunities, which all have a record field assigned to a specific project. The project, which they are assigned to is mapped through a look up field. My goal is to create a trigger, which sums every opportunity's CS_Capacity_Allocated__C field (this is the individual's capacity reservation) that is assigned to the same project and create a total capacity value to be mapped into a newly created CS_Reserved_Capacity__C field (this is all the individual's capacity reservations added together). One could then view the total project capacity on each opportunity.

A Roll Up Summary would be ideal for this situation; however I cannot establish a Master-Detail relationship on the opportunity with the project object, nor can I establish a Roll Up Summary on the project because the "Summarized Object" drop-down menu does not allow me to acces the opportunities option.

This has left me, from what I believe, with the need to develop a trigger. I have authored the following code; however it has confronted me with several error messages, which I have been fixing along the way. It has just recently sent me the following error message

Error: Compile Error: Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1

I cannot seem to work this one out. The code is as follows:

```
Trigger addReservedCapacity on opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    set <string> projectNames = new Set <string>( ); 
    List <decimal> projectAllocations = new List <decimal>( );
    decimal reservedCapacity = 0;
    integer i = 0;

    // instantiate the variables.
    for (opportunity opportunity: trigger.new) {

        If (opportunity.assigned_cs_project__c != null) {
            projectNames.add (opportunity.assigned_cs_project__c);}
        }

        // if the opportunity has an assigned project add the name of the project to a set.


        if (projectNames.size( ) > 0 ) {
            map <string, decimal> mapNames = new map <string, decimal> ( );

            for (opportunity obj : [SELECT Id, name, assigned_cs_project__c, cs_capacity_allocated__c FROM opportunity WHERE assigned_cs_project__c IN : projectNames] ) {
                mapNames.put(obj.assigned_cs_project__c,obj.cs_capacity_allocated__c);
            }

            // create a map and query the opportunity records looking for records that have matching project assignments to the created set. 
            // return the found record’s id, name, project assignment and reserved capacity
            // put the project assignment into the map as the key and the reserved capacity as the value.

            projectAllocations = mapNames.values();

            // set the projectAllocations list to the reserved capacity values in the map.

            for(i = 0; i <= mapNames.size(); i++){
                reservedCapacity = reservedCapacity  + projectAllocations.get(i);
            }

            // sum the lines of the list

            opportunity.cs_reserved_capacity__c = reservedCapacity;

            // set the CS Reserved Capacity field in the Projects object to the calculated reserved capacity.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your requirement properly, you want to get the sum of CS_Capacity_Allocated__C  of all opportunities related to a project record.(the project of the opportunity in trigger.new). right ?

I guess the below trigger will do it, not tested though.
Let me know if this helps.

```
Trigger addReservedCapacity on opportunity (before insert, before update) {

set <string> projectNames = new Set <string>( ); 
set<id> opId = new set<id>();
List <opportunity> projectAllocations = new List <opportunity>( );
decimal reservedCapacity = 0;
integer i = 0;
for (opportunity opportunity: trigger.new) {

    If (opportunity.assigned_cs_project__c != null) {
        projectNames.add (opportunity.assigned_cs_project__c);
    }
}

for(opportunity op : [select id,cs_reserved_capacity__c ,cs_capacity_allocated__c, assigned_cs_project__c from opportunity where assigned_cs_project__c IN :projectNames])
{
    opId.add(op.id);
}
decimal totalsum;
for(Aggregateresult ag : [select SUM(cs_capacity_allocated__c)sn from opportunity where id IN: opId]){
          totalsum = decimal.valueOf(ar.get('sn'));
}
for(opportunity o : [select id,cs_reserved_capacity__c ,cs_capacity_allocated__c, assigned_cs_project__c from opportunity where assigned_cs_project__c IN :projectNames]){
    o.cs_reserved_capacity__c  = totalsum;
    projectAllocations.add(o);
}

if(projectAllocations != null){
    update projectAllocations
}
```

Comment: Hi Ajay, I appreciate your help. I am walking through the code now. I am getting the following error on the following line. 

Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: decimal at line 21 column 22 
                  
 totalsum = decimal.valueOf(ag.get('sn'));

Comment: Remove line 19, and try using this instead line 21 : string totalsum = string.valueOf(ar.get('sn'));
Also, the list "projectAllocations" in line 5 , make it of opportunity type.

Comment: Ajay, it just saved without error. I am going to to do a few test cases. Thank you. I do appreciate the help. I will post and mark this answer as best when I find out if it works as needed. Again, thank you.

Comment: Does this mean anything to you? It just came up when i tried to edit an opportunity....

Comment: Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger addReservedCapacity caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: addReservedCapacity: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 006g0000008WbrhAAC; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 006g0000008Wbrh) is currently in trigger addReservedCapacity, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []: Trigger.addReservedCapacity: line 31, column 1

Comment: Yes Cole, the error is generating because we are trying to update an opportunity before update or insert.

Comment: change the for loop in line 23 to this one : for(opportunity o : [select id,cs_reserved_capacity__c ,cs_capacity_allocated__c, assigned_cs_project__c from opportunity where id != trigger.new[0].id and assigned_cs_project__c IN :projectNames]){ 
It will update the opportunities other than the opportunity in trigger.new.
Let me know if this helps. If you want to update all opportunities, change the trigger to after insert, after update

Comment: Ajay, You have been a great help. An error message told me to put a colon in front of trigger.new after WHERE id! = trigger.new[0].id  . I did this. Now it is explaining : " Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: if at line 29 column 0 
" this line is the following :

Comment: if(projectAllocations != null){

Comment: do it as -- WHERE id! =: trigger.new[0].id
and in line 29, update projectAllocations ; // add the semicolon

Comment: Oddly there already is a semi-colon

Comment: if(projectAllocations != null){
    update projectAllocations ; }

Comment: the error is still the same ?

Comment: Yeah it is. Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: if at line 30 column 0

Comment: if(projectAllocations != null){
    update projectAllocations;
}

Comment: just add a curly bracket "}" in the end of trigger. i guess a bracket is missing

Comment: I thought the same thing. I'll keep trying to troubleshoot. If you think of anything let me know. Thank you for your help ajay, if I can get this working I will be sure to write an excellent review.

Comment: ok no problem, and i'll be waiting for your review. Thanks

Comment: Ajay, I figured out the problem, it is fixed. I hate to keep bugging you and I thank you for your patience, but the SELF REFERENCE FROM TRIGGER error message is still occurring even after you suggested fix. Any other ideas?

Comment: did you try making the trigger - after insert, after update ?

Comment: yes; however it showed a bit of a different error:

Comment: Apex trigger addReservedCapacity caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: addReservedCapacity: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 006g0000008WbrmAAC; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, addReservedCapacity: maximum trigger depth exceeded Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for

Comment: [006g0000008Wbrh] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrm] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrh] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrm] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrh] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrm] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrh] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrm] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrh] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for

Comment: [006g0000008Wbrm] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrh] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrm] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrh] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrm] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrh] Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate for [006g0000008Wbrm]: []: Trigger.addReservedCapacity: line 33, column 1

Comment: I know this error. Make an apex class , for example :
public with sharing class helperclass{
 public static boolean bool = true;}
In the trigger, add this line : if(helperclass.bool != false){     and add this line before the  line "update projectAllocations" - helperclass.bool = false;
Do this, your error will be resolved

Comment: add the line --- if(helperclass.bool != false){ just after your trigger starts ie: line 2

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: helperclass.bool at line 2 column 5

Comment: did you create an apex class first ? with name helperclass ?

Comment: I did not, what would its purpose be?

Comment: make the class.. its purpose is to stop the trigger from running recurrsively..

Comment: ok, i'll do some reading on helper classes - never used one before. Thank you for your help. I will not forget to write a review once I have found a solution.

Comment: just make the class, and add the 2 lines i told you, and dont forget to mark as best asnwer plz if it helps

Comment: I absolutely will

Comment: Ajay, my apologies I did not see your comment "I Know this error" it totally escaped me. Now it makes sense. Thank you. Doing it now

Comment: When I go to edit and save the record the CS Reserved Capacity field is not being updated. It remains blank. Any idea why? I see that the final line of the code only updates the projectAllocations list, is there a way to map these values back into the record?

Comment: does this CS Reserved Capacity field update on any other opportunity of the project object ?

Comment: No it doesn't update on any other opportunity

Comment: well i cant do any more help on this mate without creating the same scenario myself.

Comment: Ajay, you have been a remarkable help. Thank you for your patience. Top notch stuff. I will figure it out and let you know if I come up with anything. Again, thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to give you a postive review other than just giving you "best answer"

Comment: yes, give a up vote

Comment: don't have a good enough reputation. Some day.

Comment: It works. My mistake. You are brilliant - had to eliminate the WHERE id! =: trigger.new[0].id because we changed it to after insert after update.

Comment: yep there you are

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use `opportunity` and `Opportunity` (notice the capitalized O) because Apex is not case-sensitive. Have you tried naming your variables inside those for loops something else than 'opportunity'? Like 'opp'?

```
for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
{
    ...
}
```

This naming might be causing your errors, as the compiler might be trying to reference the class instead of the object.

Comment: Hi Renato, doesn't seem to be the solution; but thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you still getting a compilation error? Is it the same as before?

Comment: Yes it is, or was, I am trying Ajay's (the above comment) new code currently

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Fawcett( salesforce MVP) has developed a  Declarative Rollup Summary Tool which does Roll up summary calculations for look up relationship.

You can read about this in Salesforce Development libary through this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Declarative_Rollup_Summary_Tool_for_Force.com_Lookup_Relationships)
or by visiting his [blog](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/07/new-tool-declarative-rollups-for-lookups/)

Advantages of this approach is : it is more declarative in nature and you don't need to know much apex coding to use this, plus this is available via managed package.

I was also trying to find any  limitations. Found  rules to limit records for roll up calculations are still not available. Check comments in his blog to know more about that but he is defintely planning future enhancments on this.

Lastly a proper testing in sandbox is always recommended.